# Unable to connect java program with ms access

Tags: java

"i have tried every posible thing like ucanaccess and configuring MS access driver in control panel but still not able to connect t ms access"
i am getting the errror "Could not set up JDBC: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"

i am using jdk 8 and yeah my os is windows 7 64 bit...and ms office 2013 which is 64bit aswell..

my actual code is has like 500-600 lines..i am posting just the connection part

```
 try {
                                    DBInterface.doInit();
                                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:company","","");
                                    DBInterface.checkConnection(con.getWarnings()); // connection OK? 
                                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from "+tableName+" where "+cols[m]+" = '"+searchString+"'");
                                    if(rs.next())
                                    {
                                        searchColumnName=cols[m];
                                        break;
                                    }

                                             // Close the statement
                                        stmt.close();

                                        // Close the connection
                                        con.close();

                                } catch (SQLException se) {
                                  System.out.println("inside check section"+se);
                                }
```

Comment: What version of java are you using? What operating system are you running on? Windows?

Comment: Post some code, please

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java 8, you cannot use the JDBC-ODBC Bridge because it has been removed.  Please read the [Oracle Java JDBC-ODBC Bridge](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) page for more information.